# How to map and find lazily in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections

Suppose I have a list `xs: List[X]` and functions `f(x:X):Y` and `g(y):Boolean`. Now I need to find the first `y = f(x)` so that `g(y) == true`.

```
def findY(xs: List[X], f: X => Y, g: Y => Boolean): Option[Y] = ???
```

I can do it with `xs.map(f).find(g)` but I don't want to traverse the whole list `xs`. I don't want to use streams either. How would you suggest implement `findY` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a view

```
xs.view.map(f).find(g)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
xs.map(f).find(g)
```

just turn it around

```
xs.find(x => g(f(x)))
```

In both cases `Option[X]` is returned.

---

If you want `Option[Y]`, a recursive method would do the job:

```
  @tailrec
  def findFirst[X, Y](xs: List[X], f: X => Y, g: Y => Boolean): Option[Y] = {
    xs match {
      case Nil =>
        None

      case h :: t =>
        val y = f(h)

        if (g(y)) {
          Some(y)
        } else {
          findFirst(t, f, g)
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What type does it return ? I need `Option[Y]` but not `Option[X]`. I will update the question.

Comment: Thank you for the update. However the "tailrec" solution looks too complex to me.

Comment: You're welcome. Now and then you might encounter a situation where a tailrec is quite simple. They are not that complex :-)

Comment: If you want to convert the Option[X] to an Option[Y] you could just map it, as in `xs.find(x => g(f(x))).map(f)`

Comment: Then you also calculate `f` twice, like in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to use `collectFirst`, which also returns an `Option`.

```
xs.collectFirst{case x if g(f(x)) => f(x)}
```

The only downside is that you evaluate `f(x)` twice if you find something that matches.
I'm not sure if it is somehow possible to bind the result `f(x)` to some variable.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about `collectFirst` but did not want to calculate `f` twice.

Comment: Yea, it really depends on the cost of `f`.